# Nokia lumia 1020 USB Mass storage access in C++

Tags: c++, usb, storage, nokia, usb-mass-storage

I am trying to write a software component in Windows 7 that can detect the connection of Nokia lumia 1020 to the PC. Once the connection is detected, the software will fetch all the images in the folder Computer\ \Phone\Pictures\Camera Roll\

I found no code example on how to do that so far... Wonder who have solution for that... If the solution is in c++ it would be perfect!

tujlcares

Answer (score 1):

I worked on Windows Phone and I know the API is really restricted (or not complete at all..) and a lot of **essentials** functions were **not present**

If you can't find anything on internet.. maybe you can't directly access the massive storage and you have to look for an other way..